# Join two xpath returns

Tags: python, xpath

My question is how to join the output of two xpath expressions before printing it. I need this to proper inserting into MYSQL database.
Lets say I have

```
    <fieldset class="fieldgroup group-ingred">
        <strong><a href="/log/www"><span class="ingredient">Have1</span></a>- </strong>30gramm,<br />
        <strong><span class="ingredient">Have2</span> - </strong>50gramm,<br />
        <strong>And</strong><span class="ingredient">Have3</span>.<br />

        ##################  there are a lot of similar lines here

    </fieldset>
```

So, I can get something like:

```
Have1
30gramm,
Have2
50gramm,
Have3
```

with this python code:

```
for v in doc.xpath("//span[@class='ingredient']/text() | //fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']/child::text() "):
    v =unicode(v)
    print v
```

But I want something like that

```
Have1 30gramm,
Have2 50gramm,
Have3
```

Join strings like that(this is just an example) didn't help me, because it outputs one string instead of three.

```
 date = ' '.join(td.text for td in doc.xpath(//span[@class='ingredient']/text() | //fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']/child::text() ))
     print(date)
```

So, how to join output of two xpath expressions before printing it in for loop?

Comment: Erm, I don't know Python well, but this seems like `for td in doc.xpath('//table/tr[@id = "something"]/td'): print td.text` ?

Comment: U miss the main question. The question is how to join the results of two xpath queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would join them with [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). Given that you use a for-loop to iterate over them.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for i in itertools.zip_longest(range(3), range(15,20)):
    print(i)


(0, 15)
(1, 16)
(2, 17)
(None, 18)
(None, 19)
```

In your case the range would be your xpath queries split up like this:

```
doc.xpath("//span[@class='ingredient']/text()"), doc.xpath("//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']/child::text() ")
```

Comment: Yep, thats work, I think. It prints me same symbols: u'\u0422, which looks fine but wrong encoding.  But when I try to insert it in sql it outputs sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. I don't know, what wrong with that

Comment: I do not know Python-SQL. I think that you may not be able to pass tuples to it. If this answer helps, then you can mark it as solution so others will not waste time.